# Where to find default Ubuntu purple wallpaper without animals?

Tags: desktop-background, default

Where to find official Ubuntu purple wallpaper without animals?

Every new version gets new codename and default wallpaper with this animal. Would it be possible to get it without animal?

Comment: Not only the animals but the background itself changes for every release. For example, observe the [background of Dingo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwX1A.jpg) and [that of Ermine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUqGS.jpg). I don't think there's any standard purple wallpaper.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQKK_Xjndi_xHUlmbXpZcze2IslXQ:1573321789577&q=official+Ubuntu+purple+wallpaper&tbm=isch&source=univ&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKK_Xjndi_xHUlmbXpZcze2IslXQ:1573321789577&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRgYqz2N3lAhWSEVAKHXLCBowQsAR6BAgJEAE&biw=1920&bih=974

Comment: Feel lucky you're not going for Xfce4 Wallpapers.  https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/xfce-wallpaper-cat-bug  ;) ;) ;) You might actually like https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/a-look-back-at-every-ubuntu-default-wallpaper

Comment: @Terrance last link was the best showing history of all wallpapers. It appears most did not have an animal.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the official Ubuntu purple wallpaper without animals is warty-final-ubuntu.png. warty-final-ubuntu.png wallpaper is provided by the ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial package in Ubuntu 16.04. Download the ubuntu-wallpapers_16.04.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb file from its [official Ubuntu webpage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ubuntu-wallpapers/download) and extract the warty-final-ubuntu.png file from it using the Archive Manager application.

The below wallpaper image is compressed to 75% of the scale of the original 4096 x 2034 pixels warty-final-ubuntu.png wallpaper.

[image]

Change  the wallpaper from *Settings* → *Background* → *Picture* tab → select a picture → press *Select* button (in 18.04) or *Settings* → *Background* → *Add Picture* (in 20.04).